# Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -emitcheckpoints

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

I'am trying to build this :

```
     PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup geth --datadir ./Node1/new- 
     node-1 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 -- 
     rpccorsdomain="*" --ws --wsorigins="*" --miner.gastarget 3300000 
     --miner.gaslimit 80000000000 --emitcheckpoints --raft --raftport 
     59001 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 29101 --rpcapi 
     admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft  
     --port 28101 --unlock 0 --password password.txt  
     2>>./node_logs/node1.log &
```

but this doesn't work. In node1.log Ihave this output flag provided but not defined: -emitcheckpoints and even I execute the command without -emitcheckpoint, I don't get flag provided but not defined: -raft
 I'am trying to launch a quorum node and I'am using raft as the consensus algorithm.

When I downloaded quorum using

```
   git clone https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum.git
   cd quorum
   make all
```

I get an error :

```
  build/env.sh go run build/ci.go install
  build/ci.go:61:2: use of internal package github.com/ethereum/go- 
  ethereum/internal/build not allowed
  Makefile:29: recipe for target 'all' failed
  make: *** [all] Error 1
```

when I go to build/ci.go:61:2 I have this instruction

```
  "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/internal/build"
```

Do anyone know how to solve the problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the `flag provided but not defined` message means that you are running a standard Ethereum geth executable, not Quorum.
You need to make sure the Quorum `geth` is the first one found in your path.

To build Quorum, follow the steps in the documentation. Ensure you have a valid version of golang (try 1.10.3 or 1.10.4) and that your `GOPATH` is set up correctly.

Comment: I am setting up Quorum from scratch: https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/Tutorials/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/ As I was posting the question, the "related" section brought me here. Of course I need to use `geth` provided by `quorum`. To be fair I would prefer `quorum` executable to be called `quorum` otherwise easy to make mistakes. `Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -raft  -raftport`